# Saving a .xls file as .xlsx file through VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I save a .xls file as .xlsx.

When I try to open the converted .xls file it says that the book may be damaged but when I do it manually it works.

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    Dim xFd As FileDialog
    Dim xFdItem As Variant
    Dim xFileName As String
    Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If xFd.Show = -1 Then
        xFdItem = xFd.SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
        xFileName = Dir(xFdItem & "*.xl*")
        Do While xFileName <> ""
            With Workbooks.Open(xFdItem & xFileName)

'-------------HERE GOES MY CODE so it's not worth putting it---------------------

                Dim IntialName As String
                Dim sFileSaveName As Variant
                IntialName = "Sample"
                sFileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=InitialName, _
                  filefilter:="Libro de Excel (*.xls), *.xls")

                If sFileSaveName <> False Then
                    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs sFileSaveName
                End If

            End With
            xFileName = Dir
        Loop
    End If
End Sub
```

How can I save my .xls file into .xlsx?

Comment: Is there any reason your `fileFilter` is for `xls`? Seems like you want it to be `.xlsx`?

Comment: When i put .xlsx it saves correctly but when i try to open it the error of the data or book may be damaged appears @BigBen

Comment: Would also specify the `FileFormat` in the `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs` line.

Comment: I'll try it in a moment @BigBen

Comment: Like this ? ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs sFileSaveName fileformat:=51 @BigBen

Comment: Or you can use the enum member `xlOpenXMLWorkbook` instead of hard-coding the `51`.

Comment: Thank you @BigBen i solved it with your help.